What is the best practice to send payload when saving form data with Reference field?
I have a form with Country Field as a dropdown.
<mat-select>
  @for(country of control.countries; track choice){
     <mat-option [value]="country.id">{{ country.name }}</mat-option>
  }
</mat-select>

and my .Net API is as below
public class Test
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int CountryID { get; set; }

        public string StudentID { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }
}

What is the best practice to send Country to the API, should i send ID or Value and validate that in the API controller.

Opinion-based question. What is the mentioned Value, you mean the name or? It also depends on how you process/store data in the back-end. ID should be encouraged as it is unique and using the (foreign key) reference to the country table. So you no need to modify the country name in different tables, although it is quite rare that country declares to be rename like recent case Turkey changes to Tukiye.

Say i have a Country Table with ID and CountryName and the CountryID is referenced in another table. So from the client side, should i pass CountryID or CountryName?

From your code, understand that you are trying to create/update Test record. By passing the CountryId to back-end,  you can directly insert into DB (assume that the passed Country ID is valid). Otherwise, if you pass CountryName, in your back-end you need to query to get the Country record by country name to get the id. To me, it is like a unnecessary step.

Good practice says that you should always send the ID since it is unique.
Lets say you sent the value instead, and the country table gets mutated in the meantime, what would happen if you had {Id:1 Value:'Greece'} and {Id:2 Value:'Greece'}? In that case you wouldn't know which one to reference.

you can send the country.id to validate it with the backend that is the best practice.
